# To generate PDF in report format

Tags: ios, pdf, core-graphics

I have generated PDF using CoreGaraphics in which i have passed line by line string which i want in PDF. But now i want to generate it in report format. And the data will vary as it is coming from web service. Report format will have three columns and N no. of rows(depending upon the data).

How to generate it please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to build the output line by line. you have to format them line by line... ect... the iOS has no word processing framework, if you want to implement it, you have to develop it for yourself or you should find 3rd part code for it. I've built a repo for it for myself it was not a big deal, to create the basic multicolumn tables and paragraph, various page orientation support, header/footer, page numbering (current of total) took 2 days to work out it.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution..

http://www.ioslearner.com/generate-pdf-programmatically-iphoneipad/

I have the used above tutorial and in the drawText method, i have used drawInRect: for individual string for particular column.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this framework: https://github.com/htsoft/RSReport